# Passing many environment variables to Rails application ran by Unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell, unix, environment-variables, unicorn

I need to pass a large number of environment variables to Rails application ran by Unicorn web server. The [sample unicorn init script](https://github.com/defunkt/unicorn/blob/master/examples/init.sh) has the following lines:

```
APP_ROOT=/home/x/my_app/current
<...>
INIT_CONF=$APP_ROOT/config/init.conf
<...>
test -f "$INIT_CONF" && . $INIT_CONF
```

So I created a `$APP_ROOT/config/init.conf`, put all my variables there like this:

```
VAR1=value1
VAR2=value2
```

I even made this file executable (not sure if it is necessary)

And restarted Unicorn. But `ENV["VAR1"]` **returns nothing** in my application...

Is it supposed to work this way? If yes, what am I doing wrong? If no, then how can I pass many env vars into Rails app in a clean way? (without polluting global environment or putting all of them in the command line)

**Update** My investigation showed that shell file like this:

```
. init.conf
echo $VAR1
```

works as expected. But this one:

```
. init.conf
ruby -e "puts ENV['VAR1']"
```

does not. So `.` imports code into the script but env vars set this way are not transferred further.

Comment: What should be inside of init.conf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to "export" the variables from within the config file. Does it work if you put

```
export VAR1=value1
export VAR2=value2
```

into the config file?

Comment: Great! It works the way I want it to be. And my own investigation helped me to understand how `.` command works. So just setting `VAR1=value1` is not creating env var, it is kind of local var (not present in `env` output)

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using [foreman](http://ddollar.github.com/foreman/), specifically for its use of `.env` files as defined [here](http://ddollar.github.com/foreman/#ENVIRONMENT).

Comment: Thanks, this works, but requires introducing another execution layer. Though I already got a closer answer (exporting variables), this one is useful too, I learned more about foreman. Many thanks.